# Using BeautifulSoup to find a attribute called data-stats

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm currently working on a web scraper that will allow me to pull stats from a football player. Usually this would be an easy task if I could just grab the divs however, this website uses a attribute called data-stats and uses it like a class. This is an example of that.

`<th scope="row" class="left " data-stat="year_id"><a href="/years/2000/">2000</a></th>`

If you would like to check the site for yourself here is the link.

https://www.pro-football-reference.com/players/B/BradTo00.htm

I'm tried a few different methods. Either It won't work at all or I will be able to start a for loop and start putting things into arrays, however you will notice that not everything in the table is the same var type.

Sorry for the formatting and the grammer.

Here is what I have so far, I'm sure its not the best looking code, it's mainly just code I've tried on my own and a few things mixed in from searching on Google. Ignore the random imports I was trying different things

```
# import libraries
import csv
from datetime import datetime
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml.html as lh
import pandas as pd

# specify url
url = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/players/B/BradTo00.htm'

# request html
page = requests.get(url)

# Parse html using BeautifulSoup, you can use a different parser like lxml if present
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
# find searches the given tag (div) with given class attribute and returns the first match it finds



headers = [c.get_text() for c in soup.find(class_ = 'table_container').find_all('td')[0:31]]

data = [[cell.get_text(strip=True) for cell in row.find_all('td')[0:32]]
        for row in soup.find_all("tr", class_=True)]

tags = soup.find(data ='pos')
#stats = tags.find_all('td')

print(tags)
```

Comment: were you after all tablesor only specific ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `get` method from BeautifulSoup to get the attributes by name
See: [BeautifulSoup Get Attribute](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes)

Here is a snippet to get all the data you want from the table:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.pro-football-reference.com/players/B/BradTo00.htm"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

# Get table
table = soup.find(class_="table_outer_container")

# Get head
thead = table.find('thead')
th_head = thead.find_all('th')

for thh in th_head:
    # Get case value
    print(thh.get_text())

    # Get data-stat value
    print(thh.get('data-stat'))

# Get body
tbody = table.find('tbody')
tr_body = tbody.find_all('tr')

for trb in tr_body:
    # Get id
    print(trb.get('id'))

    # Get th data
    th = trb.find('th')
    print(th.get_text())
    print(th.get('data-stat'))

    for td in trb.find_all('td'):
        # Get case value
        print(td.get_text())
        # Get data-stat value
        print(td.get('data-stat'))

# Get footer
tfoot = table.find('tfoot')
thf = tfoot.find('th')

# Get case value
print(thf.get_text())
# Get data-stat value
print(thf.get('data-stat'))

for tdf in tfoot.find_all('td'):
    # Get case value
    print(tdf.get_text())
    # Get data-stat value
    print(tdf.get('data-stat'))
```

You can of course save the data in a csv or even a json instead of printing it

Comment: Thats exactly what I was trying to find. The get() can find attributes with obscure names? I'm assuming thats how it works

Comment: Yes that's right. If this is good for you please accept the answer and up it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what exactly you're trying to extract, but this might help you a little bit:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/players/B/BradTo00.htm'

page = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(page.text, "html.parser")

# Extract table
table = soup.find_all('table')
# Let's extract data from each row in table
for row in table:
    col = row.find_all('td')
    for c in col:
        print(c.text)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Okay, Sorry for the bad explanation. I want to the whole table. Including the headers and the years. And then I want to eventually be able to write that table into a csv file.  Your version of the code works the best obviously, but I'm still not sure how to get the headers or the years.